# how to get the address of a member function within a class

Tags: c++, hook, code-injection, malware

I'm trying to get the address of a member function. Basically I'm trying to get the offset between a windows api function loaded in memory and my function.

This is what I've tried to get the address:

```
   NTSTATUS (NTAPI myntquerydirectoryfile)(
        HANDLE hFile,
        HANDLE hEvent,
        PVOID pApcRoutine,
        PVOID pApcContext,
        IO_STATUS_BLOCK* ioStatus,
        PVOID pBuffer,
        ULONG bufferSize,
        FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS infoClass,
        BOOLEAN singleEntry,
        PUNICODE_STRING pFileName,
        BOOLEAN restart
    )
    {

        cout << "my func" << endl;

    };


    typedef  NTSTATUS (*pmyhook)(HANDLE hFile,
        HANDLE hEvent,
        PVOID pApcRoutine,
        PVOID pApcContext,
        IO_STATUS_BLOCK* ioStatus,
        PVOID pBuffer,
        ULONG bufferSize,
        FILE_INFORMATION_CLASS infoClass,
        BOOLEAN singleEntry,
        PUNICODE_STRING pFileName,
        BOOLEAN restart);

    pmyhook = &myntquerydirectoryfile;
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Here it is.............. well.... it says here i cant post some thing thats too long.

Comment: got the codes right here.

Comment: Just use its name. That becomes its address via the compiler.

Comment: So how would you go about printing the address of a function from within a class? I tried to do a typedef for a function pointer and then assign it to the member function of that class. It didnt help.

Comment: I've answered that. It's pointless you telling us what you think you did without showing us what you actually did. What a `typedef` has to do with printing an address is another mystery.

Comment: You can _edit_ your answer to add the code.

Comment: well u can have a look at the codes on the link below.

Comment: link removed.........

Comment: Links to code are not acceptable here. Edit it into your question.

Comment: link removed......... its still not letting me post the whole thing, but basically what im trying to do is get the address of ntquerydirectoryfile and the address of my hook function and calculate the offset, so that i can build the jmp to myntquerydirectoryfile. I am having trouble getting the address to my hook function from within the class.

Comment: Nobody asked for the whole thing. Just the *one or two lines of code* where you 'tried to do a typedef for a function pointer and then assign it to the member function of that class'. The ones you mentioned above.

Comment: **EDIT IT INTO YOUR QUESTION.** You've been told that enough times. You can see for yourself that code in comments is *completely and utterly illegible,* and also that it can hide characters.

Comment: Sigh. Could you please now use code formatting on the code, for the same reason.

Comment: And now please enlighten us as to what exactly you mean by 'I am having trouble'.

Comment: well when i try to compile the code using codeblocks, it give me some kind of error where the pointer is assigned to the address of myntquerydirectoryfile.  This is what it says....... expected unqualified-id before '=' token

Comment: A `typedef` defines a *type*, not a variable. You need to define a *variable* of that type, and assign it.

Answer (score 2):

This code snap shows how to get address of class member functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class A 
{
public:
    void test() 
    {
        // Address of member function test(), is the value of &A::test
        printf("Address of function is: 0x%X\n", &A::test);
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.test();
}
```

Comment: Well, im trying to get the address of the function test from within the class. But the actually works if we try to print the address from main.

Comment: @jammy47 I don't see why that is a problem. Please see my edited answer. If you want to get the address within the class, just move the line  into the class.

Comment: I just checked and the code works. I really appreciate all the help i have received here today, especialy from Martin Zhai. Thanks a lot. Just bear with me cos im new here and trying to learn a thing or 2 about malware and info security.  Basically what i am trying to achieve is code injection via createremotethread. The class that ive created has a function that gets the address of ntquerydirectoryfile and tries to replace the first 6 bytes. To create the jump, i need the offset between my function which is within the class(so i cant make an object out of the class) and the api.

Comment: Well, i would have gladly done that bro, i appreciate ur help today. Its just that i couldnt really express my problem properly and the answer u provided doesnt exactly solve the problem in hand. I guess i will have to learn how this site works and try again. But thanks anyways.

Comment: I re-read your second comment above, and you said, *I can't make an object out of the class*. If so, how can you call the member function without an object of it? Is your member function *static*?

Comment: 'need the offset between my function which is within the class(so i cant make an object out of the class)' doesn't make sense. You don't need to make an object to get a member function address, contrary to what @Aganju stated in his wrong answer.

Comment: Basically im using virtuallocex to allocate space, writeprocessmemory to write class (data) to the process address space, createremotethread to run the first function within the class that gets the address of ntquerydirectoryfile and place a jmp to my hooking function. If u know about inline hooking u will know that we need to calculate the offsets between the real and fake function to create the jump, thats what im trying to do and to create that jump i require the address of myhook within the scope of the class that ive created. I dont know if im explaning this right lolz, but thanks a ton.

Comment: Sigh. 'Within the scope of the class' has no meaning, unless you mean `A::` as given in this answer. The member function has a fixed absolute address which does not depend on any scope. You've been told this about six times already. This answer gives a correct solution. I don't know why you're even discussing it further.

Comment: Agreed with @EJP. No matter in which scope (class or out of class) you require the address, it will be all the same.

Comment: Okay guys, i was finally able to get the address of my function using the codes above. Thanks a million both EJP and Martin Zhai. Now if i can only accept the answer above!

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's not allowed and not recommended.

```
void (Class_Name::* FuncPointer)() = &Class_Name::Func_Name;
```

`FuncPointer` will point to the class method.

Better use static function or the lambda feature in C++ 11.